# Rails и данные БД

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    layout "admin"
      def index
        @category = Category.all
      end
    end
```

Получаю ошибку

> uninitialized constant Admin::CategoriesController::Category

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Vladimir Gordeev](/users/532/vladimir-gordeev)](/users/532/vladimir-gordeev) Так я таблицу так и делал,

```
    rails g model Category title:string description:text
```

Получил такую миграцию:

```
class CreateCatigories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :catigories do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

И такую модель:

```
    class Catigory < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

P.S. Все понятно, неправильно назвал базу данных, catigory вместо category.

Answer (score 1):

Создать модель `Category`, очевидно.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦, эй, это не я комментарий в ответ превратил.